# Open source WPF SQL Syntax Highlighter?

Tags: visual-studio, controls, wpf-controls, syntax-highlighting

I need to display a SQL Script in my application I am making.  It would be nice if this script was syntax highlighted.

Are there any open source/free WPF syntax highlighters out there?

(NOTE: I am using Visual Studio 2008 and/or 2010 and T-SQL.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/AvalonEdit.ashx
not so easy to use, but you can implement any kind of higlighting and intellisense too

Comment: This is for SharpDevelop, not Visual Studio

Comment: no this has nothing to do with SharpDevelop, is just *used* by SharpDevelop as you can use in your project. As an example I used it in this http://www.felicepollano.com/2010/05/19/NHibernateWorkbench.aspx to provide custom HQL intellisense.

Comment: you have to write the SQL xshd yourself, because it doesn't read the old winForm xml format (I tried it...), if you already have this file, it'd be nice if you could share it :)

Comment: Please let me correct my comment; see this: http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/p/10468/28886.aspx#28886

Comment: @Coolstraw unfortunatly @Johnny does not like my reply ;) But in any case is good to know, thanks.

Comment: @Felice heh I can see that :).

In fact, I'd like to add something, I've just succeeded in using SQL Syntax HL. Two more things that need to be done because creating the SQL.vshd isn't enough, an entry to this file should be registered in the file Resource.cs (in the xml files directory), the SQL.vshd has to be set as "Embedded Resource" in visual studio otherwise a FileNotFound exceptions raises up ;). Other than that, it worked like a charm.

Comment: @CoolStraw congratulation for succeeding using AvalonEdit, that is a great component. If you find time to blog about your work it would improve the community knowledge

Comment: @Felice thank you man. I will in fact try to pull out an article about the full set up of this component whenever I get time, and indeed it is a seriously great component, with an easy as hell to use API (especially for code completion when needed).